# What's the best way to implement an SCPI command tree structure as Python class methods?

Tags: python, class, interface, instrumentation

SCPI commands are strings built of mnemonics that are sent to an instrument to modify/retrieve its settings and read measurements. I'd like to be able to build and send a string like this: `"SENSe:VOLTage:DC:RANGe 10 V"`

With code like this:

```
inst.sense.voltage.dc.range('10 V')
```

But it seems like a very deep rabbit hole and I'm not sure I want to start down it. Loads of classes for each subsystem and option....

Would a better approach be something like:

```
def sense_volt(self, currenttype='DC', RANG='10 V'):
    cmdStr = 'SENS:VOLT:' + currenttype + ':RANG: ' + RANG
    return self.inst.write(cmdStr)
```

It's trivial to just implement the commands I need and leave `inst.query(arg)` and `inst.write(arg)` methods for manually building additional commands, but I'd like to eventually have a complete instrument interface where all commands are covered by autocompleteable methods.

Comment: Clever idea, but unless you are a compiler nerd and are going to machine generate this, I would go with your analysis, that says: rabbit hole. :-)

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a balance between the multitude of classes rabbit hole, and the decision logic rabbit hole of just a sense() method with multiple arguments that must be parsed, sanity checked, etc.
Making a ton of methods for each subsystem a la `sense_volt(...)`, `sense_curr(...)`, `sense_freq(...)`, etc. is probably the way to go, but if someone has a cleverer idea...

Comment: Do you have a complete list of all possible commands, e.g. as a text file? Then auto-generating any of the two approaches should be rather easy.

Comment: I could probably copy them out of the instrument manual fairly easily (cut-paste from the PDF) and I'm fairly sure I could process it all. I'm not sure about the actual code generation while processing the commands, though.

Comment: @Jim, Old thread but, were you able to do what you wanted ? I'm interested to know if you made it work and how !

Answer (score 0):

I managed it, though I'm pretty unhappy with the results. It's been three years since I touched any of this, so I'm not sure why I did some things the way I did. I know I had a lot of trouble wrapping my head around organizing everything for portability. I'm sure that now, after a long wait, I'll be inundated with suggestions for how I should have done it.

I wrote parsing functions to interpret SCPI commands. They can separate the command from the arguments, determine required and optional arguments, recognize queries, etc. For example:

```
def command_name(scpi_command):
    cmd = scpi_command.split(' ')[0]
    new = ''
    for i, c in enumerate(cmd):
        if c in '[]':
            continue

        if c.isupper() or c.isdigit():
            new += c.lower()
            continue

        if c == ':':
            new += '_'
            continue

        if c == '?':
            new += '_qry'
            break
    return new
```

The command from `CONFigure[:VOLTage]:DC [{<range>|AUTO|MIN|MAX|DEF} [, {<resolution>|MIN|MAX|DEF}]]` can be parsed as `conf_volt_dc`, or `conf_dc`. I did not use the abridged option in my experiments. I think some of my dissatisfaction stemmed from the extra-long method names.

I wrote a builder script to read the commands from a file, parse them, and write a new script with a "command set" class extending a "command handler." Every command is parsed and converted into one of a few boilerplate methods, such as:

```
query_str_no_args = r'''
    def {name}(self):
        """SCPI instrument query.
         {s}
         """
        cmd = '{s}'
        return self._command_handler(command=cmd)
'''
```

The parser also includes a command handler class to process commands and arguments. Each command is parsed from its example text, ala `>>> _command_handler(0.1, 'MAX', command='CONFigure[:VOLTage]:DC [{<range>|AUTO|MIN|MAX|DEF} [, {<resolution>|MIN|MAX|DEF}]]'`. Arguments (if any) are validated, and the command string is rebuilt and sent to the instrument,

```
class Cmd_Handler():
    def _command_handler(self, *args, command):
        # command string 'SENS:VOLT:RANG'
        cmd_str = command_string(command)

        # argument dictionary {0: [True, '<range>, 'AUTO', 'MIN', 'MAX', 'DEF'],
        #                      1: [False, '<resolution>', 'MIN', 'MAX', 'DEF']}
        arg_dict = command_args(command)
        if debug_mode: print(arg_dict)
        for k, v in arg_dict.items():
            for i, j in enumerate(v[1:]):
   ...

        # Validate arguments
        # count mandatory arguments
        if len(args) < len([arg_dict[k] for k in arg_dict.keys() if arg_dict[k][0]]):

   ...

        if '?' in cmd_str:
            return self._query(cmd_str + arg_str)
        else:
            return self._write(cmd_str + arg_str)
```

When the builder is done, you end up with a big script (the Ag34401 and Ag34461 files were 2600 and 3600 lines, respectively) that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from scpi.scpi_parse import Cmd_Handler


class Ag34461A_CS(Cmd_Handler):

...

    def calc_scal_stat(self, *args):
        """SCPI instrument command.
         CALCulate:SCALe[:STATe] {OFF|ON}
         """
        cmd = 'CALCulate:SCALe[:STATe] {OFF|ON}'
        return self._command_handler(*args, command=cmd)

    def calc_scal_stat_qry(self):
        """SCPI instrument query.
         CALCulate:SCALe[:STATe]?
         """
        cmd = 'CALCulate:SCALe[:STATe]?'
        return self._command_handler(command=cmd)
```

Then you extend *this* class with your short, sweet instrument class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyvisa as visa
from scpi.cmd_sets.ag34401a_cs import Ag34401A_CS   # Extend the command set


class Ag34401A(Ag34401A_CS):
    def __init__(self, resource_name=None):
        rm = visa.ResourceManager()
        self._inst = None
        if resource_name:
            inst = rm.open_resource(resource_name)
        else:
            for resource in rm.list_resources():
                inst = rm.open_resource(resource)
                if '34401' in inst.query("*IDN?"):
                    self._inst = inst
                    break
        if not self._inst:
            raise visa.errors.VisaIOError

        assert isinstance(self._inst, visa.resources.GPIBInstrument)

        self._query = self._inst.query
        self._write = self._inst.write
```

I also have a SCPI instrument parent class that I was trying to fill with *all* of the star commands (*IDN?, *CLS, etc.) I wasn't happy with the previous results and was intimidated by some of the star commands' mounting complexity (some of which seemed really instrument-specific), and abandoned it. Here's the first bit

```
class SCPI_Instrument(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def query(self, message, delay):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def write(self, message, delay):
        pass

    # *CLS - Clear Status
    def cls(self, termination = None, encoding = None):
        """Clears the instrument status byte by emptying the error queue and clearing all event registers.
    Also cancels any preceding *OPC command or query."""

        return self.write("*CLS", termination, encoding)
```

In the end, the documentation I was able to squeeze into it wasn't as helpful as I wanted. The autocomplete wasn't able to prompt for arguments by name, and having **every single command** suggested was less helpful than I expected. Trying to keep the import paths straight was difficult enough for me, much less someone who might end up using my code.

Ultimately, coding has never been part of my job description, and I was moved to a position where experimenting with instrument control is even less possible.